Exponential Regression dependent variable with dummy variables or numerical average of each category?
My dataset includes toxin concentrations (continuous, dependent variable) for different size classes (5mm increments) of juvenile fish (categorical, independent variable).  The smallest size class is 25-30mm and largest is 70-75mm.  I am trying to find a model to best explain this data and it appears that a exponential regression should be best. To make the dependent variable (size class) continuous, I took the mean of the range of the class, see below.

When I fit the exponential model and plot it over my data, it does not fit well and goes below zero.  I believe this is because my data does not start near zero as it is not truly continuous.

An interesting point I have been thinking about is that when these fish emerge from eggs they are about 15mm long, so that is the lower limit at which my model could explain.  Is it appropriate to give dummy variables to these size classes say, 1-11?  I believe this would fix the issue with my data stating at 25-30mm.   How do I include the fact that the smallest possible range of the dependent variable for this model is 15mm?
My code to make the model:
     comboexpmodel <- lm(log(TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW) ~ Sizenum, data = Combo)
     summary(comboexpmodel)

Call:
lm(formula = log(TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW) ~ Sizenum, data = Combo)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.02874 -0.46896  0.08997  0.31126  1.23767 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.11243    0.60203   3.509 0.002692 ** 
Sizenum     -0.05158    0.01130  -4.564 0.000275 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6556 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5507,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5242 
F-statistic: 20.83 on 1 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.0002753

And my code to make the graph:
comboexpfunc <- function(x){
  exp(2.11243-0.05158*(x))
}

comboexpscatter <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = Combo, mapping = aes(x = Sizenum, y = TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW)) +
  geom_function(fun = comboexpfunc, color = "red")

comboexpscatter


If you have an exponential regression, it should never predict negative numbers since exp()>0. Add your data or the code and output, and we may determine what went awry.

I have added my code!

This is called a log-linear model in my field, since you have a logged outcome and an unlogged covariate. Exponential regression usually entails an untransformed outcome with $\exp()$ wrapped around a linear function of the coefficients in the estimation. A Poisson model is one example.
To fix this problem in the log-linear model, you need to deal with retransformation bias when you define your function. See an example here. That should shift the curve up.
Here's a reproducible example using something that resembles your data:
library(tidyverse)

fake_data <- tibble(
  Sizenum = c(30, 35, 37, 40, 42, 43, 45, 50, 53, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 67, 70),
  TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW = c(6.2, 2.2, 1.0, 4.0, 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
)

m<-lm(log(TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW) ~ Sizenum , data = fake_data)

# Incorporate Duan Smearing
comboexpfunc <- function(x){
  exp(m$coefficients[1] + m$coefficients[2] *(x))*mean(exp(m$residuals))
}

comboexpscatter <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = fake_data, mapping = aes(x = Sizenum, y = TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW)) +
  geom_function(fun = comboexpfunc, color = "red") + geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue")

comboexpscatter

This produces:


Great, thank you so much!
